# Losing config.yml location for arena after reload

Tags: java, bukkit

I have a plugin that lets you create arenas and save the locations.
I've put the locations in the *config.yml* but I still lose them.

Here is the `onEnable()` method:

```
public void onEnable() {

    new Joining(this);
    getLogger().info("Final Frontier enabled!");

}
```

And the command that lets you create new locations:

```
if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("create")) {
        if (args[1] != null && !games.containsKey(args[1])) {
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW
                    + "You have created game " + ChatColor.GREEN + args[1]);
            p.sendMessage(ChatColor.YELLOW
                    + "Make sure to set the spawn point for both "
                    + ChatColor.RED + "attacking "
                    + ChatColor.YELLOW + "and" + ChatColor.AQUA
                    + " defending " + ChatColor.YELLOW + "teams!");
            numberOfPlayersOnMap.put(args[1], 0);
            games.put(args[1].toLowerCase(), p.getLocation());
            playerLimit.put(args[1], 12);
            gamesList.add(args[1]);
            config.set(args[1], p.getLocation()); // IMPORTANT
            saveConfig();
            return true;
        }
}
```

Comment: You should not be storing Locations directly to the config. You should serialize the player's location into a String which you can save and load easily.

Comment: However, I'm still a newbie, and do you know any good tutorials on that that actually explain instead of making you copy code? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should really be posting these questions on the spigot forums, these sort of questions are off topic on stackoverflow and you going to find a lot more people (who all know about Bukkit) willing to help you over there.

You shouldn't just save the raw location object to a file. A simple way to do this would just be to save the coordinates and then create a new location from them when you want to load the data.

To write the data you could do something like this:

```
Location loc = p.getLocation();
config.set(args[1], loc.getWorld().getName() + "," + loc.getBlockX() + "," + loc.getBlockY() + "," + loc.getBlockZ());//Writes the actual data to the config file
```

Then you could parse that data by reading the whole string you wrote previously by and splitting up the individual parts:

```
String location = config.getString(args[1]); //Reads the raw string
String[] parts = location.split(","); //Splits it up into each part
Location location = new Location(Bukkit.getWorld(parts[0]), Integer.parseInt(parts[1]), Integer.parseInt(parts[2]), Integer.parseInt(parts[3]));//Creates a new location with the raw data
```